# Sqlite: How to show results X to Y

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to sql (and sqlite) and so far I have learned that I need to use count to get the number of rows returned by a query. However if I get for example 10'000 results and would like to divide them into 10 "pages" I would like to show only results 0-1'000 on one page , 1'000-2'000 on another page and so on.

How should I write a sql query that shows only the results I am intrested in? I guess I would have to do something like this:

```
select *
from sometable
where somecol like '%whatever%'
   AND resultcount > 1000
   AND resultcount < 2000;
```

I apologize if this has been answered before but I do not know what I should search for and so far I have not found any solutions that are simple enough for a beginner ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the LIMIT and OFFSET feature of sqlite.

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable
WHERE somecol LIKE '%whatever%'
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000
```

`LIMIT X OFFSET Y` is a LIMIT of X records, with a Y OFFSET

so `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 50` will return 10 records, with a 50 record offset.

---

There is also `LIMIT <skip>, <count>` syntax if you prefer that style

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the "LIMIT" part of a SELECT statement.

The complete documentation for the SQLite select statement, including LIMIT, can be found here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

An example:
If you want to get 10 rows from a table, stating with row 50, you would use

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 50,10
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable 
WHERE somecol like '%whatever%''
LIMIT 100 OFFSET x
```

where x is the offset of where the records should start returning from.